# Точность double

Tags: c, c++

При выводе на экран значение double следующими спосабами:

```
double delta=0.0034;
cout<<fixed<<delta<<endl;
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(19)<<delta<<endl;
```

Получаются результаты:

```
0.34
0.3999999999999999998
```

Я никак не могу понять, почему во втором случае получается 0.3999999999999999998 ?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Double имеет точность в 15 значащих цифр, а Вы пытаетесь вывести 19.

```
cout<< fixed << setprecision(15) << delta << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в двоичном представлении 0.34 является бесконечной периодической дробью. И при конечной длине мантиссы не может быть представлена точно.